# Quick Sort Algorithm realisation

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

i've already sought information for the quick-sort algorithm. But i still can not realize it on C. I'm trying but the Quicksort function doesn't work at all. I Can't find errors in my code. Please, help me to understand what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int a, int b)
{
    int temp = 0;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int Partition(int p , int r, int A[r - p + 1])
{
    int j = 0;
    int x = A[r - 1];
    int i = p - 1;
    for(j = p - 1; j < r - 1; j++) {
        if(A[j] <= x) {
            i = i + 1;
            swap(A[i], A[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(A[i], A[r - 1]);
    return i + 1;
}

void Quicksort(int p, int r, int A[r - p + 1])
{
    int q = 0;
    if((p - 1) < (r - 1)) {
        q = Partition(p ,r , A);
        Quicksort(p, q - 1, A);
        Quicksort(q + 1, r, A);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int A[] = {10, 5, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 7, 6};
    int i = 0;
    int length = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);
    Quicksort(1, length , A);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Your `swap()` function will do nothing. It will swap the contents of its local copies, and return. The data you called it with (`A[i], A[j]`, etc.) will be unchanged. Consider either passing (and receiving) *pointers* to integers, or implement `swap()` as a macro.

Comment: actually, I didn't. I guess i'll try now.

Comment: thanks a lot. I mess this up.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the values as pointers to the `swap` function

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = 0;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

and then change

```
swap(A[i], A[j]);
```

to

```
swap(&A[i], &A[j]);
```

and

```
swap(A[i], A[r - 1]);
```

to

```
swap(&A[i], &A[r - 1]);
```

Comment: You mean like in c++, no.